# Change Displaying color of Icon in a Combo Box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, triggers

In my WPF application I have a combo box with icons which displays an icon with particular name . These icons are represented respective to the type of the name (I have no issue in that hence would not explain that in detail)

I am trying to style this combo to ensure consistency of the application . What I am trying to do here is to give the icon the color `#047F89` when it is selected when the icon is hovered over since it has a similar color to the icon I want to give it white:

[image: Please Look at this Image]

I have been able to achieve this requirement but in the process when a item is **not selected or hovered over** the icon color has been changed to the default color of black. Instead of black I would like it to have the color `#047F89` as well.

I have not been able to figure what needs to be done here and would appreciate any help

here is my code

**My styles are as follow**s ,

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonBackground" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#047F89" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**The use of combo box**

```
<ComboBox Height="10"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          Style="{StaticResource ButtonBackground}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemCollectcion}}">
```

**Example of Combo box Resources**

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type FolderModel}">
        <Path Stretch="Uniform" 
              Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Control}, Path=Foreground}"
               Height="15"
               Width="25"
               Data="..."/>
     </DataTemplate>    
</ComboBox.Resources>
```

Comment: Have you tried `AncestorType=ComboBox`? Otherwise it might find the ComboBoxItem ancestor.

Comment: Hi @Clemens I tried that ... That Did get the Icon to show the Required color when not selected but it resulted in the icon NOT turning to white when Selected (If you look at the attached picture you will see what I am Talking about

Comment: I think what you need to do is to change the "Mouse Over" visual style of the items you placed in the Combobox and not of the Combobox style itself.

Comment: In your style make the TargetType as ComboBoxItem instead of ComboBox

Answer (score 0):

The `IsSelected` Trigger in your ComboBox Style has no effect, because a ComboBox does not have such a property.

You should instead declare a Style for the ComboBoxItem class like shown below, and perhaps also add a Trigger for the `IsMouseOver` property.

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonBackground" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#047F89" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then assign the Style to the `ItemContainerStyle` property of the ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox ... ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ButtonBackground}"/>
```

And use ComboBoxItem as AncestorType in the Binding in the DataTemplate:

```
Fill="{Binding Foreground,
       RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBoxItem}}"
```

Comment: I did try this , However now When an Item is Selected only the Name is Displayed and the Icon is completely vanished .  I tried it with Live Visual Tree to see if the Icon is invisible even tho it is present but Turns out The icon is Not displayed at all. The Icon is shown in the combo box though but when Selected Only the Name is Shown with an Empty space

Comment: What is shown now is similar to the attached image if the Icon on the Left of the Name "SmerterRegister" is taken off

Comment: btw I Do Really Appreciate your Answer and it does solve my issue to a certain extent but I cant afford to lose a working function in the process. Hope you understand :)